# Read return value from block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following block defined in my class:

```
typedef BOOL (^AlertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButtonHandler)(AlertView *alertView);
```

I call this block like so in my viewcontroller and return a boolean, as expected by the block.

```
 self.alertView.shouldEnableFirstOtherButtonHandler = ^BOOL (AlertView *alertView ) { 

     return YES; 
}
```

How would I manage to get/read the return value in my class?

Comment: Please post the code where you call the block function?

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell from your block name what it should be doing but not sure if a block is the best way to handle this; looks more like a property that should be set.

Comment: It corresponds to the UIAlertView Delegate message - (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView, which returns a bool based on some conditions in order to enable the first button in an alertview with a textfield. I am trying to implement this function in a custom alertview class and chosed to use a block (function) like the original delegate message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way of getting a return value from a block is to invoke it:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Quick brown"
    message:@"fox jumps"
    delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"over the"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Lazy dog",
    nil];
BOOL blockResult = self.alertView.shouldEnableFirstOtherButtonHandler(av);
```

Comment: Works!... Thank you very much for the quick answer, I will accept it when it is possible.